# Is $|z^2|$ entire function?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I want to know whether $|z^2|$ is entire function or not.

If I am not wrong then $z^2$ is entire but $|z|$ is not entire (Am I wrong here?)

So, now how to say anything whether $|z^2|$ is entire or not?

Comment: $\|z^2\| = z\overline{z}$ is not even holomorphic, how can it be entire?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I understand that $f(z)=\bar z$ is not holomorphic but how did you say that $z\bar z$ is not holomorphic?

Comment: Two ways: $\frac{d}{d\overline{z}}\neq 0$, hence the Cauchy-Riemann equation is not fulfilled, or: such $f$ is constant over the boundary of any circle centered at the origin, but it not a constant function.

Comment: Third way: if you look at that function as a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, the Laplacian at zero is not zero, hence it is not an harmonic function, hence it is not a holomorphic function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A real valued function cannot be entire (unless is constant), as you can quickly see checking the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations)

Comment: Unless it's constant.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Fair point!

Comment: If $f(z)$ had a complex derivative at  any $z\ne 0$ then so would $f(z)/z=\bar z,$  but $\bar z$ does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.